# Appropriate way to use Android Support Library

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library

When I created a new app, I got this

```
class NewApplicationActivity extends ActionBarActivity{... }
```

So I have read that, if you want to use a new feature from a newer API level, you better make it such that there is an alternative option for the App to combat any situation for the `minSDKVersion` that you plan to support.

Assuming this is true, lets say I decide to build my App against `targetSDKVersion = 21`(which I did in the above example), I would get the base Activity class as `ActionBarActivity`. Now this is from support library and works for older version(down to Android 2.1 I guess..).

The thing is, I am stuck with these alternative set of support libraries rather than platform libraries. Am I gonna miss something significant if this happens? Will I get a chance to incorporate the platform specific code from API 21 into my App ever? The majority of Apps are made with compatibility in mind. How do you people handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Support Libraries such as [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) (which is what `ActionBarActivity` and its replacement [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) are part of) are designed to reflect the latest platform changes and backport as much as possible. Thereby by using AppCompat, you are already using a large number of API 21 features (such as [material theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)).

Of course, there is nothing stopping you including *any* API from any level in your application: just make sure that they are guarded by the appropriate API level checks: this is exactly what many of the Compat classes in Support v4 such as [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) and [ViewCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html) do for you.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that, the Compat libs have the latest API code incorporated to maximum extent that is safely possible while also providing the alternative version of the code that is required? Do you as a developer rely heavily on the Support library?

Comment: I wrote a portion of it, as well as produced a [number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PIc-DuEU2s) [of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32i7ot0y78U) on its usefulness. The support library doesn't cover everything, but you'll find it saves you a lot of time in almost all cases.

Comment: Okay I will check the videos and everything then report back. Thank You for the response and the video links.